# Pandoc TOC to Include Heading (Section) Within Nested List

Tags: markdown, pandoc

My `example.md` markdown file is like below:

```
- # This Is Heading Lv1 <= this not showed in TOC
  - the quick brown fox
  - ## This Is Heading Lv2 <= this not showed in TOC
    - jump over

# This Is Another Heading Lv1 <= this showed in TOC
```

using pandoc command:

`pandoc -f markdown example.md -s -t html --toc`

i got no TOC for Heading within "list" or "nested list" in the html output.

(html output here is just an intermediary, because my target output is pdf.)

what I've tried and failed:

- add `{-}` identifier to the heading
- add `<article></article>` between heading
- javascript in html template (of course not my code) is working, but only when open the html file in browser

How to generates TOC for heading within nested list? please help